# CSS selector for an :after element if body has class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm desperately trying to hide an automated added image on a checkout page.

I'm trying to select the element div.panel-body:after which is on a page that has a body class.

I've tried:

```
body.offer-checkout-offer-311523 div.panel-body:after {
display: none !important;
}
```

div.panel-body is not a direct child of body that's why I used a space between the selectors instead of `>` But despite my attempts, the image does not hide.

Any clue?

Edit:

the HTML element I'm trying to edit:IT's the ::after I'm trying to target 
[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLu4q.png)

I've tried to export the whole path to the element but...

Edit2:

This is my website, It's probably easier if I show the page here: photoserge.com/offers/yDBpDfqi/checkout?coupon_code=FBPSQS 
I'm trying to hide the credit card images but only on this page. The whole site uses the same checkout page thats why I'm trying to target only this specific instance.

Comment: It is possible that your selector is not specific enough, can you show the actual CSS for the element you refer to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does your HTML look like? A minimal example would be helpful. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please share the entire source code. Otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: Is this your website or are you trying to write a user style?

Comment: This is my webiste, It's probably easier if I show the page here: https://www.photoserge.com/offers/yDBpDfqi/checkout?coupon_code=FBPSQS I'm trying to hide the credit card images but only on this page. The whole site uses the same checkout page...

Comment: I looked at your site and what you have should work, since the only selector is `panel-body::after` and your selector is more specific. Are you sure your CSS is even loading? I didn't see what you have in the inspector...which leads me to believe your CSS isn't getting picked up anywhere.

Comment: Yeah I see it in the inspector, in the header

Comment: What is your CSS file name? When I look in the inspector, I don't see your styles getting added anywhere. I see the file that's loading the credit card icons, but you might want to share the name of your file. Also, are you using a CDN or caching for your CSS? If so, you may need to clear the cache/CDN - which is why you may not see your changes.

Comment: The css is directly in the header (or at least the piece I'm adding):
in the <style> </style> (just above the Google Tag Manager script)

Comment: When I look at the source code, my CSS is showing, so I dont think that there is a caching issue there.

Comment: I just looked at your source code again and nowhere in that `<style>` tag is the CSS from your question.

Comment: Sorry I should have kept it, I had removed it. It's back there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
.checkout-panel .panel-body::after{
    display: none
}
```

I just tried by inspecting the page.

Also, if you want to target this specific page.  You will have to remember to add the css to only this page, and not add this code to a global css file.

Comment: OPs selector is more specific than what you have here and will work. I think this is an issue with OPs CSS loading.

Comment: My problem is that I dont have access to this specific page, I can only modify the template or add CSS in the header of the template. that's why my only way to select this page was through the body class that included an "ID" even though its a class it's unique

Comment: I tried your solution though, but it did not work (with the body. in front)